# Azure - Error CS0433: The type 'IAsyncDisposable' exists in both 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces,

Tags: c#, .net, azure, nuget-package

I've added the IAsyncDisposable interface to one of the classes of my project.
Everything works fine when using Visual Studio. I can compile and execute the application without any errors nor warnings.

But after committing the project to Azure and compiling there I get the following error:

> ##[error]..Web\Services\HubEventService.cs(13,41): Error CS0433: **The type 'IAsyncDisposable' exists in both 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'**
> D:\a\1\s...Web\Services\HubEventService.cs(13,41): error CS0433: The type 'IAsyncDisposable' exists in both 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' [D:\a\1\s....Web\Services....Web.Services.csproj]
> Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s....Web\Services....Web.Services.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
> Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s....Web\Client....Web.Client.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
> Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s....Web....Web.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

The code I've changed is as follows:

```
    public class HubConnectionService : IAsyncDisposable
{ 
... 

public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            if (HubConnection != null)
            {
                await HubConnection.DisposeAsync();
                HubConnection = null;
            }                
        }
}
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12209#issuecomment-578915056), you need to use the newer version of NuGet in the pipeline.